# Repeatable Metabox with wysiwyg

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

I'm looking to create repeatable metaboxes with 3 fields (name, website and description), very similar to this tutorial https://gist.github.com/helen/1593065 which serves as the foundation for my code. However, I don't fully understand how to introduce a wysiwyg editor for the description (ideally, in place of the select dropdown within the tutorial). I'm just now getting the slightest bit comfortable with php so any comments with a solution would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Handling the repeating editor is kind of tricky in WordPress as it requires custom JavaScript code to work on the DOM. WordPress doesn't support repeating fields by default. Besides, the code you're reference to is 7 years old.

I'd suggest using [Meta Box](https://metabox.io) plugin, which has a [Meta Box Group](https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-group/). It helps you build repeatable groups easily with some PHP code.

If you don't want the repeating group of fields, you can still make a single field repeatable. This feature is called [clone](https://docs.metabox.io/cloning-fields/) and is supported in the free version of the plugin.

Comment: I will certainly look into the plugin. I didn't realize a repeating wp editor required more intense JavaScript code than what I have in there now. Currently, I do have the meta box group "clone-able" (with js from the example), but with an image uploader and textarea inputs. I was hoping the wp editor would be an easy swap but it sounds like that may not be the case. Hopefully the plugin will fit my needs. Thanks.